# datatype of marriage status? (java)

Tags: java, variables, types

May I know what datatype to use for Marriage Status? 
as far as I know Marriage status is either married or not married,
is it possible to use `boolean` in this case? true/false 
else what am I supposed to use? 
Thanks!!

```
boolean marriageStatus;
if(marriageStatus = true)
   {
       //
   }
```

Comment: one `=` is assignment, two `==` is for testing value equality. So, `if (marriageStatus == true)` **or** just `if (marriageStatus)`. Don't forget to assign a value to `marriageStatus` before testing its' value.

Comment: I think `boolean` makes sense here. Also, You can just say, `if(marriageStatus)` instead of `if(marriageStatus == true)`

Comment: @user2004685 `boolean` makes no sense here. What does `true` mean? Name of variable makes it unclear. If it was named `married` or something like that, a `true` value would be clear, but `status == true` is meaningless.

Comment: Are you certain marriage status is Boolean? Single, Married, and what about Divorced, Widowed, etc. It may not matter for your use case, but something to consider.

Comment: @Andreas I was talking about the DataType. Of course the variable name matters and you are right it should be something like `isMarried`.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest an enumerator for that, just because a marital status is (like the name suggest) a status and not just a `true/false` variable

```
enum MaritalStatus {
    SINGLE, 
    MARRIED, 
    DIVORCED, 
    WIDOWED, 
    COMPLICATED
}

public class Person {
    private MaritalStatus maritalSt;
    private String name;
    ....

}
```

the best part is that you can use this in a switch-case in a very confortable, so you don't need to take care about if-else or similar

```
public void fooMethod() {
    switch (myMaritalSt) {
    case DIVORCED:
        System.out.println("well sometimes that happens");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `COMPLICATED`. They are is `IS_xxx`. *(of course, "complicated" is not a "just" ;-)*

Comment: Hmmm, "they are is". I'm making no sense. Was supposed to say "they are all". *<sigh>*

Answer (score 2):

If your are only interested if a person is married or not then a `boolean` is fine. But you should name the variable so that is clear what `true` or `false` actually means.

`marriageStatus` does not accomplish this, better name the variable `isMarried`.

Comment: Field should be `boolean married`. Getter method is then `boolean isMarried()`.

Comment: @Andreas you take your job very seriously